# How can I figure out which step I've just executed in Cucumber's AfterStep hook?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I'm writing a method to be executed on the `AfterStep` callback for Cucumber.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#step-hooks

How can I figure out which step was executed before this hook was called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AfterStep` hook only receives the scenario as parameter.

What you can do, is count the steps, and then get the current one:

```
AfterStep do |scenario|
  @step ||= 0
  p scenario.steps[@step].name
  @step += 1
end
```

This will print, in turn, the names of each parameter

Comment: Nice!  If you're inside of a Scenario Outline and running an Example, this becomes:

`p Array(scenario.scenario_outline.send(:steps))[@step].name`

Answer (score 3):

Using gem cucumber 2.1.0 and scenario outlines, the scenario object in "Afterstep" is just a test result status, it does not contain the name of the step. I had to use "Before" (called before the first step) that contains a test list.

```
require 'logger'

$logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

Before do |scenario|   

    @count = 0       
    @tests = Array.new

    scenario.test_steps.each{|r|
         if( r.name != "AfterStep hook")
              @tests << r
         end
     }
 end

 AfterStep do |scenario|  # run after each step

     $logger.info(@tests[@count].name.green)
     @count += 1;

 end
```

The logger is required because 'puts' only display when the scenario outline ends.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

The api has changed slightly. you now need to use 'to_a'

i.e. the Alex Siri's line above would be changed to:

```
  p scenario.steps.to_a[@step].name
```

Comment: Api has changed again. Both suggestions are no longer working

Answer (score 1):

[Vince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3679240/vince) has a good solution, I would recommend a refactor:

```
Before do |scenario|
    @tests = scenario.test_steps.map(&:name).delete_if { |name| name == 'AfterStep hook' }
end
```

You can use the @tests.count instead of the @count variable

I would have made this as comment but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 1):

The API has been changed... Based on [afterhook doc](https://app.cucumber.pro/projects/cucumber-ruby/documents/branch/master/features/docs/writing_support_code/after_step_hooks.feature) you can get the [result](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/cucumber/cucumber-ruby-core/Cucumber/Core/Test/Result) **(Cucumber::Core::Test::Result)** and the [step](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/cucumber/cucumber-ruby-core/Cucumber/Core/Test/Step) **(Cucumber::Core::Test::Step)** like this:

```
AfterStep do |result, test_step|
  #do something
end
```

You can get the step name with:

```
stepName = test_step.text
```

or

```
stepName = test_step.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out as follows:

```
Before do |scenario|
    ...
    @scenario = scenario
    @step_count = 0
    ...
  end

  AfterStep do |step|
    @step_count += 1
  end
```

That keeps the step number updated.  In order to get the step name:

```
@scenario.test_steps[@step_count].name
```

Answer (score 0):

Vince's answer is great! and SMAG's refactor is cool ! but when I applied the solution on my cucumber test project, I got an error:

```
 undefined method `name' for #<Cucumber::Core::Test::Step:>
```

so, maybe the answer can update as below:

```
Before do |scenario|
    @tests = scenario.test_steps.map(&:text).delete_if { |text| text == 'AfterStep hook' }
end
```