# how do I extract the step name from AfterStep inside of calabash-cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, calabash-ios

I'm using the AfterStep hooks inside calabash-ios/cucumber.

I want to know the last executed step inside my hook.

```
AfterStep do |scenario|
  puts "Step: #{scenario.name} #{scenario.title} #{scenario.gherkin_statement}"                                                                   
end
```

I can see that the scenario is passed in, but how do I access the currently running step? I don't see any information inside the [scenario docs](http://cukes.info/api/cucumber/ruby/yardoc/Cucumber/Ast/Scenario.html) regarding this.

I would assume that the step would be passed into the `AfterStep` hook. Any clues?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912864/how-can-i-figure-out-which-step-ive-just-executed-in-cucumbers-afterstep-hook will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer to [this example code](https://github.com/AlexDenisov/tdd_calc/blob/3855f2f1bafe68843da4e4eb65d08a36566ff9db/features/support/hooks.rb), which works with step indexes within the AfterStep hook.

**Example:**

```
CALABASH_COUNT = {:step_index => 0, :step_line => nil}

#TODO change this approach as it breaks scenario outlines
Before do |scenario|
  begin
    CALABASH_COUNT[:step_index] = 0
    CALABASH_COUNT[:step_line] = scenario.raw_steps[CALABASH_COUNT[:step_index]].line
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "#{Time.now} - Exception:#{e}"
  end
end

AfterStep do |scenario|
  CALABASH_COUNT[:step_index] = CALABASH_COUNT[:step_index] + 1
  raw = scenario.raw_steps[CALABASH_COUNT[:step_index]]
  CALABASH_COUNT[:step_line] = raw.line unless raw.nil?
end
```

The [Behave BDD framework](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/), in Python allows a more simple `step.name` type accessor, but others seem more difficult, requiring the above technique of counting the current step and then using the index to find the name from the raw steps text.

Comment: Works for me. Sad that the hook does not give you that, but this is a good work around.