# Get cucumber scenario step name

Tags: cucumber, watir

I try to get step's name in hooks file:

```
AfterStep do |scenario|
  step = scenario.steps.find { |s| s.status == :failed }
  if step.name.include?("failed step")
    puts "Failed step is: #{step}"
  end
end
```

But when I run a scenario I'm getting  next error:
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'steps' for #<Cucumber::Core::Test::Result::Passed:0x42a58b8>`

I use Cucumber 2.4.0. Is another way to get scenario step name?

Comment: The API for AfterStep hook seems to have changed - ie a scenario is no longer passed as an argument. From [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34863392/1200545), the answer suggests you'll need to retrieve/store the name in the Before hook instead.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is next:

```
AfterStep do |result, step|
  puts step.name
end
```